# element.loader.split is not a function

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I get this error

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/LoadersList.js:58
    if(element.loader) return element.loader.split("!");                                    ^TypeError: element.loader.split is not a function
at getLoadersFromObject (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/LoadersList.js:58:43)
at LoadersList.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/LoadersList.js:78:12)
at Array.map (native)
```

this is my webpack

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {


entry: {app: './src/app.js' },
  output: {filename: 'public/build/bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: 'public/build/bundle.map' },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, loader: 'babel-loader',query: {
        presets: ['stage-0','react','es2015'],
        plugins: ["transform-decorators-legacy","transform-class-properties"]
    } },
      { test: /\.css$/, loaders: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ] },
      { test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'file?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]'  },
      {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,    loaders: [
      'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
      'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
    ]}
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I just changed loader to loaders

Bbut i still get this error and warnings 
https://paste.ofcode.org/3bdwaGaYcysDg3dACfyNQnu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your last loader.

```
{test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,    loader: [
  'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
  'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
]}
```

That has an array, not a string. `loader` expects a string, `loaders` expects an array. Change the key to `loaders`, plural:

```
{test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,    loaders: [
  'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
  'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
]}
```

Comment: I changed it. But now I get this error
https://paste.ofcode.org/3bdwaGaYcysDg3dACfyNQnu

Comment: that's not a webpack error, that's a babel error. Look here for instance
https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/3200

Comment: try removing the babelrc files from the modules that are giving you errors

Comment: there is babelrc file in node_modules/auth0lock  . Should i delete this file? Is this safe thing to do ?

Comment: read the error you pasted completely, you'll notice there are 2 babelrc files that are throwing errors. to stop those errors, you can remove them, or if you don't feel comfortable doing that, rename them to something else so they aren't picked up by babel. it is absolutely a safe thing to do. the public version of those modules are in npm. you can simply reinstall the module if anything goes wrong

Comment: thanks Ananth. I was able to get rid of all the errors. But the warning is still there 

WARNING in ./public/imgs/common/blueimp-gallery/video-play.svg
DEPRECATED. Configure gifsicle's interlaced option in its own options. (gifsicle.interlaced)

can you please tell me how to get rid of this?

Comment: going to accept your answer. I will add this error in next question.